# d3: why is variable set inside d3.json not accesible outside?

Tags: svg, d3.js, tree

Consider the following code

```
var height = 500, width = 700;
var root;
var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

d3.json("abc.json", function(error, flare) {
  root = flare;
  alert(root); // This prints object object
});

alert(root); // This prints undefined
```

The alert inside d3.json displays correctly that it is an object but the alert outside d3.json prints undefined. How can I make root accessible outside d3.json? I need it because depending on some user inputs in the page, I may need to make some manipulations in the d3 tree, for example, remove some nodes. These user inputs are on some controls separate from the d3 tree.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `d3.json` runs asynchronously.

It is made clearer by this example:

```js
root = 'initial value';

d3.json("abc.json", function(error, flare) {
  // This runs after `abc.json` has been fetched
  root = flare;
  alert(root); // This prints object object
});

// This runs before `abc.json` has been fetched
alert(root); // This will show 'initial value'
```

The callback function will be called after the current execution context has terminated and `abc.json` file has been fetched, even if it is fetched from the cache of the browser.

Hence, you will notice that the alert for `initial value` comes before the alert with `[Object object]`.

Comment: Thank you. So now I understand why I am not able to access the variable. Then how can I manipulate the tree after the tree has already been loaded? I cannot do it in any event handlers of any node or link of the tree. This is because I need to do manipulations based on some user actions in a control apart from the tree (e.g. selection in some drop down).

Comment: Define a third function which is called after the JSON is loaded and call the same function from the event handlers.

Comment: By event handler do you mean event handler of the d3 tree? But I cannot call the 3rd function from any of the d3 tree event handlers. Suppose the html page has a drop down, which is not a part of the d3 tree. I want to make some changes in the tree depending on what the user selects in the drop down. Can this be handled in an event handler?

And how can I make sure that the 3rd function will be called after the json is loaded, when the loading of json is asynchronous?

Comment: The third function will be the one which draws/updates the tree map. It will test whether data has been loaded and will read the various `values` from various DOM input elements (including drop-downs) to draw/update the tree. However, the design is now extending beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying that. Meanwhile just want to mention that I am using the following sample:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083

I need to add code to manipulate the tree in that.